# DeprecationWarning: Module scipy.linalg.blas.fblas is deprecated, use scipy.linalg.blas instead

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, theano

I've just now installed theano on my machine but when i try to use it - i.e `import theano`
I get this 'DeprecationWarning':

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/lib/_util.py:35: DeprecationWarning: Module scipy.linalg.blas.fblas is deprecated, use scipy.linalg.blas instead
  DeprecationWarning)
```

When I comment out the above line the error doesn't show. I've tried updating scipy, numpy, theano.. but nothing works.

Any ideas on what's causing this warning and how to get rid of it?

Comment: It's just a deprecation warning. Nothing I would worry about. Theano apparently tries to import `scipy.linalg.blas.fblas`, which is replaced by `scipy.linalg.blas.blas`.

Comment: I don't like ignoring warnings (I'm a nerd i know..) is there anything i can do about it?

Comment: Sure, the source code is on github. You can always write a patch and discuss with the developers.

Comment: What versions of Theano are you using? That deprecation warning should have been fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/1150) dated 8th Jan 2013

Comment: @ali_m one of the last sentences in the PR is: `My only complaint was that it first tries a deprecated form of the API and the falls back to the supported form, but I understand that in this case, it is somewhat tricky to fall-back to the old code.` - It seems that this is not fixed yet.

Comment: @cel Ah, I assumed that it was fixed because I've never seen that deprecation warning with scipy v0.14.1. Whether or not you see the warning might also depend on your version of scipy. Either way, it's certainly nothing to worry about, since `scipy.linalg.blas.fblas` will just redirect to `scipy.linalg.blas`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for the comments. @cel

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid a Deprecation Warning. If you don't want it to show up you could add the following to your code.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```